# ¿Cómo instalar librerias MySql Connector/C++ en Xcode YOSEMITE?

Tags: mysql, c++, xcode, macos

¿Cómo hago para instalar las librerias MySql connector/C++ en Xcode? especificamente en YOSEMITE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debemos tener instalado en orden:

- ***Xcode***
- ***Cliente y Servidor MySql***, descargar desde la página oficial: [MySql Server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)
  Al instalar MySql Server, también se nos instala el cliente.
- ***Command_Line_Tools*** para Xcode, descargar de la página oficial: [Página Apple para desarrolladores](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2Fdownload%2Fmore%2F&rv=1).
- ***MacPorts***, descargar de la página oficial: [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php)
- ***cmake***, instalar con MacPorts: ejecutar en la CLI (Terminal) la siguiente línea

  ```
  sudo port install cmake
  ```

---

Una vez instalado TODO lo anterior, podemos comenzar a instalar las librerías boost y MySql Connector/C++.

**Estos pasos seguirlos al pie de la letra:**

1. ENTRAMOS al sitio oficial de *boost C++ LIBRARIES*: [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/quickbook/install.html), y SEGUIMOS los pasos de la sección **"Mac OS X, using macports"**. Una vez finalizados estos pasos...
   Ejecutamos desde la CLI (Terminal-Linea de Comandos):

   ```
   sudo port install boost
   ```
2. DESCARGAMOS el repositorio oficial el archivo que contiene el **código fuente** de [MySql Connector/C++](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp/tree/1.1), esto es muy importante, no bajarse el instalador precompilado, sino el source ya que lo vamos a compilar a mano nosotros. Seleccionamo el boton verde que dice **Clone or Download** y seleccionamos Download ZIP, descomprimimos y en la terminal ejecutamos las siguientes líneas de comandos:

   ```
   cd /RUTA/A/LA/CARPETA/DESCOMPRIMIDA
   cmake -DMYSQL_CXXFLAGS=-stdlib=libc++ .
   make clean
   make VERBOSE=1
   sudo make install
   ```

   Ya tenemos instaladas la librerías y headers de boost y MySql Connector/C++
   así que nos aseguramos que en la ruta `/usr/local/include` estén los archivos:

   ```
   cppcon/
   mysql_connection.h
   mysql_driver.h
   mysql_error.h
   ```

   y que en la ruta `/usr/local/lib/`, existan archivos con nombres que contengan estas líneas de caracteres `ibmysqlcppconn`

---

Hecho todos estos pasos debemos hacer un soft link de la carpeta boost contenida en `/opt/local/include`; así que ejecutamos en la línea de comandos la siguiente sentencia

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/boost /usr/local/include/
```

Ya tenemos todo listo para empezar a trabajar, así que que creamos un nuevo proyecto en Xcode y configuramos las rutas de las librerías y de los headers que vamos a utilizar en el proyecto, aclaro que estas librerías y headers son los que acabamos de instalar.

Seleccionamos el proyecto y vamos a las siguientes secciones de configuración

- Agregamos `libmysqlcppconn.7.1.1.6.dylib` (que se encuentra en `/usr/local/lib`) a `Link Binary With Libraries` en la pestaña `Build Phases`
- Agregamos la ruta `/usr/local/include` en `Build Settings -> Search Path -> Header Serach Paths`
- Agregamos la ruta `/usr/local/lib` en `Build Settings -> Search Path -> Libraries Serach Paths`

Hay dos ejemplos completos de MySql que podes seguir, a continuación te dejo los enlaces:

- [Ejemplo 1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html)
- [Ejemplo 2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html)

Comment: Ya podés agregar más links